# Number of subgroups of a certain order in an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I've been given the following problem:

Let G be an abelian group, |G|= 120 its cardinality. Given that there are exactly 3 elements of order 2:

1. What's the number of subgroups of order 15?
2. What's the number of subgroups of order 60?
3. What's the number of non-cyclic subgroups?

My attempt is as follow:

1. we have 120=$2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$ so by the fundamental theorem of abelian groups, and given that we must have exactly 3 elements of order 2, G=$C_2\times C_2 \times C_2 \times C_{15}=C_2\times C_2 \times C_{30} $ and we have $\phi(15)=8$ number of generators for $C_{15}$ and thus number of subgroups of order 15, $\phi$ being Euler's totient function.
2. I don't have an answer, but I found the group $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_{15}$ as a subgroup of the given order. I don't know how to cout the number of copies though.
3. I didn't think about it as carefully as the second point, but I'd still like an answer.

I'd like to have an overview of the general approach given the structure of an abelian group as cartesian product of cyclic groups as well.

Thanks

Comment: Please ask one question at a time

Comment: That's the complete single exercise I've been given, with the points in a sequential order. It seems wrong to me to break it down into three questions given that the points might be related.

Comment: The general case is quite tricky, apparently; see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/46115/42153) for all subgroups.

Comment: $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$ has $7$ elements of order $2$.

Comment: U(143) seems to fit the bill. Elements 12,  131, and 142 generate subgroups of order 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple errors in what you did.

0. Note that $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$ has **seven**, not three, elements of order $2$. In general, if the $2$-part of your abelian group has $k$ cyclic factors, then the group will have $2^k-1$ elements of order $2$: because if your $2$-part looks like $C_{2^{a_1}}\times \cdots \times C_{2^{a_k}}$, each cyclic factor has exactly two elements of exponent $2$ (the identity and an element of order $2$, which is unique because of the uniqueness of subgroups in a cyclic group). An element $(g_1,\ldots,g_k)$ has order $2$ if and only if each $g_i$ has exponent $2$ and at least one has order exactly $2$. So you have two choices for each component, but you need to exclude the identity element, giving you $2^k-1$ elements of order $2$.
   That means that if your group is to have *three* elements of order $2$, then you need $k$ cyclic factors, with $2^k-1=3$. That means $k=2$, so **two** cyclic factors, not three. That means you must have $C_{2^2}\times C_2$, not $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$.
1. Although $C_{15}$ has $\phi(15)=8$ generators, *they all generate the same subgroup*. You were not asked to count the number of **elements** of order $15$, you were asked to count the number of *subgroups* of order $15$. To count the number of subgroups of order $15$, you could note that any abelian group of order $15$ is cyclic, so you can count the number of **elements** of order $15$, and then **divide** by $\phi(15)$, because you are counting each *subgroup* generated by an element of order $15$ precisely $\phi(15)$ times. But you did not do that, and instead asserted that $\phi(15)$ is the number of subgroups of order $15$, which is definitely false. Instead, again consider an element $(g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4)\in C_4\times C_2\times C_3\times C_5$, figure out conditions to ensure that this element has order exactly $15$, and then divide the total count by $\phi(15)$ to get the correct value.
2. For $60$ it is trickier, because it isn't *just* the elements of order $60$. So you know that a subgroup of order $60$ must be either isomorphic to $C_2\times C_{30}$, or to $C_4\times C_{15}$; that latter is cyclic, so for that one you can proceed as in 2. But then you need to figure out the ones of the former type. Consider finding the cyclic subgroups of order $30$, and then figuring out how many ways you can add an independent element of order $2$. Note that $C_2\times C_2\times C_{15}\cong C_2\times C_{30}$.
3. You have $G\cong C_2\times C_{60}$ (figure out why). Shouldn't be hard to figure out when you have noncyclic subgroups...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'll get back to the problem as soon as I can.